# Since read has a built in variable $REPLY, why do we need to explicitly state $line or other variable

Tags: bash, read

While reading line by line, and IFS set to null, we can write:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt")
```

Is this not the same as:

```
while read -r
do
    echo "$REPLY"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt")
```

Why or when is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the `man bash`, *`If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY.`* in your second attempt there is no name so it stores in the REPLY variable by default.

example:

```
$ cat infile
1
2
3
```

---

```
$ while read ; do echo $REPLY; done <infile
1
2
3
```

but it (`REPLY` variable) doesn't set when you specify a name and it that case the current line read into the specified name instead.

```
$ while read tmp; do echo $REPLY; done <infile



$
```

> Why or when is one preferred over the other?

It's clear and up to you, when you want to use default REPLY variable for storing the lines it reads, drop the *name* argument, to store in different variable name, specify it strictly, that's all.

Comment: So I gather from both answers is what I originally suspected- in most situations, it does not really matter which version I use. However, it was new information that $REPLY is not set if I do use a named variable. As regards readability, I guess if there are more read and while loops in the script, it would make sense to distinguish them. Otherwise it is really trivial.

Comment: @Rajib, note that `read` can take multiple variable names too (it splits on `IFS` and assigns the values from left to right). e.g. `read a b <<< "foo bar"; echo $b` would print `bar`. In that context, it would be harder for it to duplicate the returned value in `REPLY` too.

Comment: Yes- I sort of hinted that in a reverse way in the question, because I did not use the IFS option with $REPLY.

Answer (score 3):

Why would one use a variable called `line`, instead of the default `REPLY`?

It helps for understanding the code if variables are named in a way that works to describe what the code is doing. Compare:

```
files=( ... )
target=...
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    something "$file" "$target"
done
```

vs.

```
a=( ... )
b=...
for c in "${a[@]}"; do
    something "$b" "$c"
done
```

Which one is clearer? If there's a bug in one, which one lends to finding it more easily?